# Difference between char* and int*

Tags: c

I'm sorry for asking a basic question that has definitely been asked before, but I just couldn't find it!
Why in C can you assign a string literal to a char*, but cannot assign an integer literal to an int* ?

Comment: That's the wrong question. The right question is "why can I not assign an integer literal to an `int *` and why can I also not assign a character literal to a `char *`".

Comment: You need code to demonstrate what you are trying to do. In C you can cast anything to anything.

Comment: Because what you are referring to as a "string literal" is actually parsed as a constant array of characters. char* var = "string" is the same as char var[] = {'s','t','r','i','n','g'};

Comment: @KerrekSB: What are you talking about, you can totally do `char *foo = "bar";`

Comment: @EOF but "bar" is not a char literal but a string literal.

Comment: @MichaelWalz: Well, the question talks about "string literal", so...

Comment: @EOF the op writes that you **can** assign a string literal to a char*, (which is of course correct)

Comment: @MichaelWalz, I'm just not sure what KerrekSB's comment is supposed to add to this.

Comment: You cannot assign string literals (character array) to `char*`. You can assign *a place of* string literals to `const char*`. Integer literals can be assigned to `int*`, converted by implementation-defined manner.

Comment: Detail: C does not define "integer literal".  It does well defined various kinds of "integer constant".  OTOH, it does define `"string literal".

Comment: @EOF KerrekSB is attempting to correct the asker's apparent misunderstanding, as the asker appears to believe that a string literal is to `char*` what an int literal is to `int*`, which it is not.

Answer (score 3):

Because a string literal is translated to an array of `char` (`char []`) during translation. C does not have a distinct string type.

As every array, it is converted for most usages (except for `sizeof`, `_Alignof` and the address-operator `&`), it is converted ("decays") to a pointer to its first element. As this is a `char *`, there is no problem assigning it to a `char *` variable or passing as a `char *` argument.

An `int`/integer constant (the C standard does not use the term "literal" here) OTOH can be converted to a pointer, but that is not what you normally want. Also the conversion is implementation defined. Thus the compiler emits a warning for such an assignment without explicit cast. To emphasise: there are very few cases you want to assign an integer constant to a pointer (e.g. embedded systems). None in typical PC programs.

To get the address of an `int` **variable**, use the `&` operator:

```
int i = 5;
int *p = &i;
```

If you need something similar to the string literal, qualify the variable `const`:

```
const int i = 5;
```

Note that this still is a single integer, so you must not add an offset to the pointer, e.g. `p[1]` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Good answer aside from "C does not have a string type." as that confuses the issue and IMO is not needed.  C defines _string literal_ and _string_ but does not define what you mean by a _string type_.

Comment: @chux: I added a word to clarify. But I think the information is neither confusing, nor unnecessary. Once you accept that it is just an `char []` and nothing else, things become much more clear. Btw. 6.2.5  describes the concept of types quite well. And the term "string" is only used in context of _string-literal_ or the string handling libraries.

Answer (score 1):

A string in C isn't a primitive data type. It is actually a 0 terminated sequence of chars. So `char *sp = "literal";` is actually working with a pointer to a sequence of chars.

An int on the otherhand is a primitive type, so when you use a literal int, it is an int with no tricks to make it look like something else.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, but then why do I remember reading (I think in The C++ Programming Language) that they only allowed an assignment of a string literal to char* because in previous definitions of C the type of a string literal was char*, but today when it's technically of type char[] it shouldn't really be allowed (but is for backward compatibility).

Comment: OP asks about _string literal_ and this answer discusses _string_.  Similar, but different.   "A string literal need not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character may be embedded in it by a \0 escape sequence."  C11 footnote 78

Comment: @Yamor: The C standard is clear that modifications of the resulting array with the literal is undeffined behaviour. Still it is not explicitly `const char []`, so assignment to a `char *` is well defined. While I agree this is problematic, it sometimes is a useful feature to provide a default string. It is not allowed in C++. Note that C++ and C are different languages. Porting rules from one to the other is more often a problem than most people expect.

Answer (score 1):

In C, a string is an array of characters. When an array is used as a the value of an expression, it's usually automatically converted to a pointer to its first element (there are some exceptions, they're not important here), so you can assign this to a pointer variable.

Other literals are not automatically converted to pointers, so you can't assign them to pointers without casting (and even if you do cast, the result is not portable). So the reason you can't do:

```
int *intptr = 123;
```

is the same reason you can't do:

```
char *charptr = 'a';
```

Note that there's nothing special about `char*`. You can assign an `int*` from an `int` array, e.g.

```
int intarray[] = {1, 2, 3};
int *intptr = intarray;
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct. An array is not always converted to "a pointer ...".

Comment: When can it be used as an r-value without being converted?

Comment: The C standard does not use the term rvalue at all, but only mentions it once in footnote 64: _What is sometimes called ''rvalue'' is in this International Standard described as the ''value of an expression''_. See the corresponding section 6.3.2.1p3 for the exceptions.

Comment: I've reworded and clarified.

Comment: You can do `int *intptr = 123;` in C, but can't in C++. (you may get some warnings) https://ideone.com/owvg2D

Comment: @MikeCAT: Yes, I covered that in my answer. But actually it is useless for PC-type programs (but very useful for embedded programming).

Answer (score 1):

A C string literal is an array of type char (composed of many chars).
An integer is a single item of type int.

This is why the syntax for assigning each to a pointer differs.

Assigning an array of type char or int to a pointer would use the same syntax, as would assigning a single item of type char or int to a pointer.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

```
char *str = "Hello";
```

what happens is just about exactly the same as if you had said

```
const char tmpstr[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
char *str = tmpstr;
```

That is, whenever you write a string constant like "Hello", the compiler automatically allocates a little static character array containing your string.  And it's perfectly okay to use this array as the initializer for a character pointer.  (There's actually a potential little discrepancy as to whether the string constant is an array of const char or not, but let's not worry about that for now.)

So if you said

```
int tmpi[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
int *ip = tmpi;
```

that would work perfectly fine, too.

But you can't assign an integer to an `int *`, because that doesn't make sense:

```
int *ip2 = 123;    /* WRONG */
```

On the right we have an integer 123, and on the left we have an `int *`,and you can't assign an integer to a pointer.

(Now, if you really want to, you can try to assign a raw memory address to a pointer, but let's not worry about that for now, either.)

Comment: The standard intentionally does not quailfy the generated array `const`, but explicitly states that modifications are UB. The consequence is that you can `char *p = "Hello";`, while `const char a[] = "Hello"; char *p = a;` should generate a warning. So you cannot make it equivalent.

Comment: @Olaf: Sure.  That's why I said "just *about* exactly the same".

Comment: It has different conversion semantic - the most important part, not just a minor difference.